# Detect Firefox mixed content blocking with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, browser

How do I detect Firefox's (or any browser's) mixed content blocking "feature" with JavaScript or jQuery?

More about Firefox's mixed content blocking:
https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/

The long story:

My company has a vendor that provides the online ordering part of our website. The online ordering is using https while our main website is using http. I was asked to restyle the vendor's online ordering pages to match the look and feel of our main site. Our vendor's online ordering pages have two iframes, one for the header and one for the footer. I updated the navigation links in the header and footer with target="_parent" and that works in all browsers except Firefox 23 because FF23 is blocking the links that point to http sources. My plan was to simply write a script to change the link target="_blank" and let Firefox users get pop-up windows instead. But now jQuery has removed the "jQuery.browser" feature in version 1.9 and says to try and use feature detection instead. So after a while googling I come here to humbly ask this question. Yes, I know I can just write plain JavaScript to detect browsers but I figure using feature detection in this case would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken as to the scope of mixed content blocking - it is present in virtually all current browsers, including:

- Firefox 23 and later, per your link
- Chrome 21 and later (http://blog.chromium.org/2012/08/ending-mixed-scripting-vulnerabilities.html)
- Internet Explorer 9 and later (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2625928)

You will need to restructure your site such that it does not load mixed content. In this case, this will probably require that you make your main website available over HTTPS.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange because FF24, IE10, and Chrome 29 aren't blocking the links.

Comment: Okay, now I'm just confused - what sorts of mixed content does your page end up containing?

Comment: The third party https site lets me use an iframe to display the header/footer to sandbox the css (not my design). So I upload a header.htm and a footer.htm that are hosted on the https site. All images and other assets are hosted on the https site. What is being blocked is when the user clicks a link in the header/footer that is at my main http site. The more I look at this the more I think this behavior was a mistake in FF23, that's why it's gone in FF24.